# class <cucumber> cannot be resolved to a type - also not able to import cucumber.junit.api.Cucumber

Tags: junit, cucumber, cucumber-junit

[image: Eclipse Screenshot]

Attached screenshot shows the project setup and jars included. Can somebody please help me what is that I would have done wrong.

Comment: You have duplicate cucumber-java-1.2.5.jar in your classpath.

Comment: I had removed the duplicate jar file but still not able to import the package cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber class is present in cucumber-junit-1.2.5.jar file.
Try to use this dependency: [https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit/1.2.5](http://maven%20dependency) in maven.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many ways to resolve this issue, finally I downloaded
this jar file cucumber-junit-1.2.5.jar and then I highlighted my project, then
clicked on Project > Properties> Java Build Path> Libraries>
Maven Dependencies > Add External Jar file  .....and opened my downloaded file and
added it to Maven dependencies and error disappeared.